# DDNS on subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, ddns

My website is hosted for me, but I have some other services (like dev sites) I keep on a local machine.

With my old ISP (who gave a static IP as standard) I added these serviced to my subdomain. Now I am with someone who doesn't offer a static IP (even as an added extra, always read the small print guys).

Is there a way to freely map my dynamic IP to the a records on my hosted domain name?

Answer (score 3):

If your current DNS hosting have some sort of API to update DNs records, you can use that to update your subdomain.example.com to refelect ypur current IP. If your DNS hosting does not supports that, you have two options

1. Move your whole domain to some other DNS provider which supports dynamic DNS (you need to switch only domain hosting, not necessary to switch registrar)
2. Create an (free) account with some dynamic DNS provider (see [list](http://talkdns.info)), setup dynamic DNS client etc. - follow your DDNS provider instructions. Then for subdomains which you want to map to your local PC, on your *primary domain* hosting, create a CNAME record - `subdomain.mydomain.com CNAME myhostname.somedynamicdns.net`.

Comment: Your list is no longer available at that URL.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few DDNS or Dynamic DNS Providers that offer free services.

1. https://www.dynu.com/en-US
2. http://www.duckdns.org/
3. http://www.no-ip.com/  <----Yes listed above

I have used no-ip.com's free and paid services. Both work very well. But I just wanted to list a few to help some people out since Dyndns went from free to paid.

Answer (score 0):

There are services which offer exactly what you are asking for, [DYNDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/) being the one I've heard the most about.

You could have the host delegate DyDNS as the master for the subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use No-IP. Our No-IP Plus Managed DNS service is $24.95 a year or $32.95 a year if you choose to transfer your domain to us. (It will add a year of registration to your domain)

Please keep in mind that this would make No-IP your new DNS provider, so you would need to replicate every current DNS record associated to your domain with us. If you need help or have answers, don't hesitate to reach out.

http://www.noip.com/plus/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a system like no-ip's free service, or any other provider that does dynamic dns mapping. Then you would have your subdomain entries be CNAMEs for the dynamic dns name you use.